# Fullcalendar show "end date" one day off

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

Fullcalendar show "end date" one day off
json is jan 12th, to 16th, but the calendar show 12th to 15th
here is the code

```
var calCon = $('.cal');
calCon.fullCalendar({
    prev: 'left-single-arrow',
    firstDay: 1,
    weekends:true,
    weekNumbers:true,
    ignoreTimezone:false,
    allDayDefault:true,
    weekNumberCalculation:"ISO",
    defaultView:"basicWeek",
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
    events: {
        url: "/calendarjson.xsp",
        cache: false
    }
})
```

here is the json

```
[{"color":"#3a87ad","id":"123","allday":"1","url":"/...","end":"2015-01-16T10:00:00.0+0100","start":"2015-01-12T09:00:00.0+0100","title":"Thomas Adrian"}]
```

[image]

I am using allDayDefault because time is not important.
What am I doing wrong?

I am using the latest fullcalender 2.2.5
I have tried to change the time but it is still the same

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FullCalendar.js uses exclusive end moments. The documentation says it [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object). It means that the end moment of an event does not belong to the time interval from start to end, but marks the point in time right after that interval.

The important point here is that you set default for allDay to true. You use `2015-01-16T10:00:00.0+0100` as endpoint for the event. But an allDay event does NOT keep time information internally in fullCalendar. It strips off the time and only keeps the date. You use `2015-01-16T10:00:00.0+0100` as endpoint. The time is stripped and end is made exclusive which results in `2015-01-15T23:59:59.0+0100`, what is the result you see in your fullCalendar. You should have used `2015-01-17T00:00:00.0+0100` as end for your allDay event, to have it span to January 16th 23:59:59.