# Event Shift for one day for all-day event on fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

Having problem for "all-day" event that an event with start Nov 10 and end Nov 12 will span only 2 days on the calendar.
Looks like the documentation for the [old version](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/Event_Object/) has the right one that I want it to work.
But with the new version, is there a way I can make it span for 3 days instead of 2 days without changing the end date?

The problem of changing the end date is that I allow user to store the end date. I don't think changing the end date from the user input is a good idea.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi! I think the best way is to handle this before events are rendered. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960971/fullcalendar-show-end-date-one-day-off

Comment: Yea, I understand that I have to change the end date one day after before events are rendered. My problem is because I use the data based on user input, so I just don't want to make them confused about changing the end date for them. Well, I guess that's my only option?

Comment: I believe you can change the date after getting it form the user and remove one day in case of showing the date back to the user.

Comment: I see.. yea, that might be the best way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you need more help on this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks like it is defined in that way  in full calendar. For example if you drop some event on 3rd march for 1 day then

start  : Mar 03 2020 00:00:00
end    : Mar 04 2020 00:00:00

Hope it helps.